# How to use Logical Operators in Comparison?

Tags: powershell

I cant figure out how to use the logical OR in a comparison in Powershell.
My code looks kinda like this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path G:\Path\Blabla -Include *.sql* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.Name -cmatch 'somefile1.sql' -or -cmatch 'somefile2.sql'}
```

However, this code does not work
-> The goal is to find those files in a folder

Comment: You have to write out a full, valid expression for each `-or` operand: `$_.Name -cmatch 'somefile1\.sql' -or $_.Name -cmatch 'somefile2\.sql'`. Note that `-cmatch` expects regular expression pattern, so you have to backslash-escape the dot.

Comment: why not use `-Include somefile1.sql, somefile2.sql` and forget about `Where-Object` ?

Comment: That has worked, thank you :)

Comment: Or use -eq instead of -cmatch.  Windows filenames aren't case sensitive anyway.  Note that -or and -and have equal precendence, unlike any other language.

Comment: And if you do use regular expression operator `-cmatch`, why not do it the regex way and use `|` (regex OR) like this: 
`$_.Name -cmatch '(somefile1|somefile2)\.sql$'` ? (the final `$` is the end of line anchor character in regex)

Comment: `'somefile1.sql', 'somefile2.sql' -ceq $_.name` [When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a Boolean value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features)